# Does my ex-GF have daddy issues?

Tags: relationships, psychology

I met this girl a year ago and a half ago. We then became friends and started dating and living together. We broke up last month due to different lifestyles and looking at life.

To start, she was a 20yo student, I am a 28yo entrepreneur when we started dating. The father of my ex gf left the family when she was 5. She said that her father just left their home and never got back.

As I mentioned above, we were living together for a year and a half. During that time, I have noticed some behavior that I haven't seen in girls I've been seeing before, nor in my friends.

My ex-gf doesn't have a true friend, even though when she meet someone, after a while she starts highlighting the negative attributes of that person. She has a small circle of "friends" - 4 or 5 people who she texts about once every few months, but currently she's not talking/texting with them. When I told her to break the ice and text her friend after the fight, she said she's not going to be the one who'll text first (and this happened also between us - when we had a fight early in the relationship, we didn't speak to each other for a while and I texted her. When we were talking about that later why I texted her, I also asked her how long she would wait until she would text me - and she said she would not).

She's constantly trying to put herself above someone - to prove she's better than her “friends”, either at life or at school (she's saying, for example, that this "friend" is looking up to her and envying her lifestyle, or she’s the most talented at her class etc.).
When she meets someone, she call them a friend immediately (even though if they have seen each other once or twice for about 15-30mins).

When we are at home, she often complained that she felt alone, lonely and she has no friends to go for a drink with etc. Eventually she's bringing this on me that I don't take her anywhere (which is impossible as a working person to be out 7 days a week). She outlines how she does not feel appreciation from me (from time to time) and so on.

She has weekly emotional breakdowns and hysterical crying about school, herself, life (eg. when she needed to move out of her old apartment, when the teacher put some adequate pressure on her) etc. She’s still claiming how independent she is, what she has done, travelled, but the truth is that I had to help her with everything. Literarily everything. Or her mother. She's on the phone with her mother daily for 1-2 hours. She’s very insecure of herself and asking me if this is good or bad, if she treated a person good or bad and so on.

She's very suspicious to everybody - to people she meets as well as to me. She is very jealous eg. when she had a roommate, she somehow came up with the thought that I like her roommate and she likes me and we want to have sex - it was obviously not true. Same with guys - we were at a party and a guy started talking to me on a bar (just small talk until our drinks were ready), my gf was sitting with some of my friends and I could feel her eyes on me. When we were walking home, she was questioning me for 15 minutes about who was that guy and why he was talking to me. Then she mentioned that there were more guys who were trying to hit on me rather than on her.

When we were home and I was tired from work or sometimes simply not in the mood, she was constantly asking me if I was not happy that she's in my apartment, if I am not happy with her etc.

I noticed that she's very sensitive about notes with her mental condition. Her teacher told her that she's not confident, unstable and sometimes self-centric. Then my ex-gf had another breakdown at home, was crying and for another week (during different situations and conversations) was randomly mentioning that she's not having any mental problems... Then during one of our fights I dropped a comment that "she has constructed a situation in her head" and she was firing this back at me for another couple days.

She was also quite oriented on money, she was buying expensive clothes even though she could not afford it and always almost begging her mother to pay for it. She enjoyed highlighting what her life standard is, she even marked herself as the "top 1%" and said that (we were on a trip in Liverpool) that "most of this lower and middle class people has some motivation to get up, but for her it's difficult, because she's already there and has a different point of view" (she never worked).

Eventually all of this has become too much for me, so we had a talk and I told that I am not happy in the relationship and that this simply doesn't work for me and we would have to figure it out, otherwise I don’t see how to maintain it further. We agreed that we would take a couple of days to think abut that and would get back together to discuss it.

The next day, she just texted me saying that she's breaking up with me.

It’s been two months now. Since I had the talk about daddy issues with my friend I am wondering about the relationship with this girl. What do you think about her based on the above I have never faced a girl anything like that, I was wondering if she has some troubles with herself, daddy issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about relationship advice not parenting advice.

Comment: I would like to add that I think you're in a toxic relationship. I know sometimes you feel like you need to work though these issues but sometimes it's best to cut your ties and move on. This person, according to you, sounds like they have some issues they themselves need to work through on their own.

Comment: I dont think anyone on here would be qualified to answer whether she has "daddy issues" or not, thats not a question that can be answered online from one post.